# mongodb error (probably firewall problem)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, discord.js

So I was making a Discord bot and when I was trying to do something with MongoDB, the error given below showed up (probably a firewall problem).

I'm using a VPS from OVH on ubuntu 22.04.

The error:

```js
node:events:491
         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
        
MongooseError: Operation `profiles.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous> (/home/olex/djs-bot/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:153:23)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
    Emitted 'error' event on Client instance at:
    at emitUnhandledRejectionOrErr (node:events:394:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:85:21)
```

This is my code:

```js
const { Client, IntentsBitField, EmbedBuilder, ActivityType, Partials } = require("discord.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const cmdHandler = require("./handlers/command.handler");
const slashCmdsHandler = require("./handlers/slashCommands.handler");
const eventHandler = require("./handlers/event.handler");

const { MONGODB_PASSWORD, MONGODB_USER } = process.env;

const uri = `mongodb+srv://${MONGODB_USER}:${MONGODB_PASSWORD}@bot.w5dpeik.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`;

mongoose.connect(uri, () => {
      console.log("Connected to mongodb");
});

const bot = new Client({
    intents: [
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildScheduledEvents,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.MessageContent,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMessageReactions,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.Guilds,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.DirectMessages,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildVoiceStates,
        IntentsBitField.Flags.GuildMembers
    ],
    partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction]
});

slashCmdsHandler(bot);
cmdHandler(bot);
eventHandler(bot);
bot.on("ready", async () => {
    console.log(`${bot.user.username} is ready to be ...`);

    await bot.user.setPresence({ activities: [{ name: "Olex7iMatix.org" }], status: "dnd" });
});

bot.login(process.env.TOKEN);
```

Comment: `buffering timed out after 10000ms`  means that your internet connection cant handle the buffering